# How to OAuth 2.0 with Retrofit Android

Tags: android, api, authentication, oauth-2.0, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit library and I wanted to implement OAuth 2.0 on every API call in order to authenticate those calls. How can I achieve that? Can you explain me step by step? I have followed some blogs but didn't understand how to do that.

Comment: Can you explain a little more what you are trying to do? Which oauth server are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I highly recommend you to check [u2020 source code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/u2020/data/api/oauth). You can achieve this with a OkHttp interceptor (Retrofit 1.x or Retrofit 2.x) or a `RequestInterceptor` if you stay with Retrofit 1.x.

Answer (score 0):

I think for the oAuth 2.0 process its better if you open directly the browser and once its done it will redirect to the redirect_url specified. You will need to register the redirect_url in your manifest as a intent-filter for the activity that will manage the response of the server.